# Octicons in Android

Tags: android, github, icons, octicons

Is there some kind of icon set that can be used in `Android` that contains icons similar to the
[GitHub Icons](https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0).  For example, the events push, pull, fork, merge, comment ...

Or is this something that is only possible in a browser?

I was looking to use the `UTF-8` encoding in a `Textview` but it did not render properly. From what I read it's a proprietary set of `UTF` character codes.

Comment: You can use FontAwesome. http://joanzapata.com/android-iconify/

Comment: Hey @dannyroa, that is a really useful library.  However, the Font Awesome Icons only contain one of the repo specific actions `icon-code-fork`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the GitHub icons. Here's the [assets folder for the official GitHub Android app](https://github.com/github/android/tree/master/app/assets) including the [TTF font](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/assets/octicons-regular-webfont.ttf). The [license](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/assets/LICENSE) is pretty permissive.

Assuming you have a `TextView` with the id `text` and the TTF file in your assets folder, you can do something like this:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Clone \uf04c");
    text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "octicons-regular-webfont.ttf"));
```

Comment: Thanks @kabuko.  This appears to be working for many UTF character code sequences except for `UTF+f009`.  For some reason this looks to be rendering an icon similar to `UTF+f00a`.  Why do you think that is happening?

Comment: @toobsco42 Nope, no idea why this is happening for you. I'd double check your work. I looked at the font `UTF+f009` seems to be rendering fine and differently from `UTF+f00a` for me.

Comment: Hey @kabuko, so i set my `TextView` like this `text.setText("\uf007-\uf008-\uf009-\uf00A-\uf00B");` and the ouptut looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/MLH0I.png

Comment: Ah, it does look like that font doesn't quite match up with the styleguide. You'll have to browse through the font with some sort of viewer and find the icon you want.

Comment: Okay I'm glad that I'm not the only one who could see this.  What kind of `viewer` are you referring to?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can use Character Map.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, and I tried using a Character Map application but it didn't quite work.